# Did the body of Saint Bernadette remain intact after 50 years, despite the conditions it was in?

Tags: biology, religion, catholic-church

According to this 2019 article in the National Catholic Register, [*The Marvelous Preservation of St. Bernadette*](https://www.ncregister.com/blog/the-marvelous-preservation-of-st-bernadette), the body of Saint Bernadette had limited decay, despite:

> given the close examinations, damp conditions, and normal decomposition observed of other sister buried in the same place.

The rosary she was holding rusted and her hand was not damaged until after her first wash by nuns in the chapel.

Was St Bernadette's body much less decayed than would be predicted?

Comment: "_…than would be predicted_" by what or whom?

Comment: The photos make it look like she's been 100% preserved, but you're really seeing a layer of wax that's been added to her hands and face like a mask, which is even mentioned in the Catholic Register. (Not an answer since that's only skin deep, but worth keeping in mind.)

Comment: @Geremia: I intended "than by science." It is clear that the claim is not "The body was perfectly preserved" but that the body was miraculously preserved in a way inconsistent with natural processes. We cannot (using only scientific skepticism as our tools) confirm that supernatural forces were at play, but we might be able to confirm that the preservation defies our understanding of the science of [taphonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taphonomy).

Comment: @Oddthinking "_We cannot (using only scientific skepticism as our tools) confirm that supernatural forces were at play_" You can say that something is not explainable by known natural processes.

Comment: @Geremia: Agreed. I think your "not explainable by known natural processes" is equivalent to my "defies our understanding of the science". Neither suggests "Therefore God".

Comment: @Oddthinking But I disagree that everything can be explained by natural processes (known or unknown).

Comment: @Geremia: That's fine, but you aren't going to be happy with the answers here, which need to stick to empirical evidence. If loaves and fishes fell from the sky, you are not going to get answers here confirming it was a supernatural miracle from God.